# Finding parent process ID on Windows

Tags: windows, cmd

## Problem

Given a process ID & command-line access on a remote Windows host, how can you find its parent's PID?

## Solution

Given Marc B's answer, we can use WMIC (Command samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jhoward/wmic-samples)) and do something like this:

`wmic process where (processid=PROCID_HERE) get parentprocessid`

Comment: If your paths are messed up (like me), then you will enjoy knowing that the wmic.exe is in "C:\Windows\System32\wbem"

Comment: It should be noted that process IDs are reused, so if the parent of a process has exited, you might incorrectly identify an unrelated process as being the parent.  (I guess you could detect this by comparing the run times for the two processes.)

Comment: Are there plans adding this as a column in Windows Task Manager?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
C:\> wmic process get processid,parentprocessid,executablepath|find "process id goes here"
```

Comment: You're awesome, thank you. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this returns its parent on first line on LHS & itself on RHS. Then if it is a parent itself, it will show more processes with itself on LHS & children on RHS.

Comment: it should return things in columnar format, in the order you specified them on the command line. You can strip off the executablepath bit to reduce it to just the pid/ppid numbers, which does make it a lot more compact.

Comment: Hey Marc, Played around with a bit, it doesn't adhere to the manner in which you specified them on the cmd line. get parentprocessid, processid & get processid, parentprocessid both spit out ParentProcessId on the lhs and processid on rhs

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me. Consistency isn't exactly a signature characteristic of BillCo.

Comment: Since `find` will match a substring, this will often generate extraneous data.  Use a `where` clause instead as shown in the other two answers.

Comment: I got this error: FIND: Parameter format not correct

Tried with both "18640" and 18640 (without "s)

Answer (score 12):

In powershell:

```
PS> wmic process  where '(processid=4632)' get 'processid,parentprocessid,executablepath'
ExecutablePath                                              ParentProcessId  ProcessId
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\com.docker.db.exe  4488             4632
```

Answer (score 8):

Based on [joslinm's solution in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486717/305973), here's a snippet of how to use this in a batch script:

```
set PID=<this is the child process ID>
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (`wmic process where ^(processid^=%PID%^) get parentprocessid /value`) do (
    set PARENT_PID=%%a
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can do something like this in PowerShell:

```
Get-CimInstance -className win32_process | where-object {$_.ProcessId -eq processId_goes_here } | select ParentProcessId, Name
```

as well you can filter by name just substitute `$_.ProcessId` with `$_.Name` property

Comment: all the other answer are deprecated in Windows 11 Insider Preview 22494.1000 WMIC is deleted, so thx for this answer